# Vaadin 14 event propagation

Tags: event-handling, vaadin14, event-propagation, componentlistener

I have a Vaadin FlexLayout component, that has a clicklistener added to it, however it has similar FlexLayout children elements, that also have clicklisteners. My problem is that, if I click on the children components, both the parents and the childrens events are fired.

Is there some way to prevent this?

Comment: This is un-implemented feature, the feature request ticket is here: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/1020

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.